# How do I get rid of this flickering box around my card?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I scroll the box flickers white.

Here's a video of it:
https://flutter-project.tumblr.com/post/656161576589672448

Here's my code:

```
body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 120,
            color: Colors.white
          ),
          Card(
            elevation: 0,
            color: Colors.white,
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),),
            child: Container(
              height: 20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF1F305E),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

The look I'm trying the achieve:
[image: Example]

Here's a video of it:
https://flutter-project.tumblr.com/post/656241232200220672

Comment: what actually happens? add screenshot/gif

Comment: I added a video

Comment: are you using modal bottom sheet? Share at least the parent widget of this card

Comment: I added more code

Comment: did you try this on real device!

Comment: Yes, I’m using my iPhone 8

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but adding a box shadow got rid of it...

```
Card(
            elevation: 0,
            color: Colors.white,
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shadowColor: Color(0xFF1F305E),
            borderOnForeground: false,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),),
            child: Container(
              height: 20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    color: Color(0xFF1F305E),
                    offset: Offset(1,1,)
                  )
                ],
                color: Color(0xFF1F305E),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.zero,
                bottomLeft: Radius.zero),

              ),
            ),
          ),
```